# Guice: object creation of unreferenced object

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have a class which should be created during the injection phase but this instance will not be referenced anywhere in the code. The way this class communicates with the others is via event bus

```
public class DefaultCounterTracker {
  private final EventBus eventBus;
  private final ReplicatedMap<String, String> trackerCache;

  @Inject
  public DefaultCounterTracker(
    EventBus eventBus,
    @Named("CountersTrackerCache") ReplicatedMap<String, String> trackerCache)
  {
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
    this.trackerCache = trackerCache;
    bindListeners();
  }

  private void bindListeners()
  {
    eventBus.localConsumer(CounterCreated.name(), (Handler<Message<String>>) event ->
    {
      handleCreation(event.body());
    });
    eventBus.localConsumer(CounterDestroyed.name(), (Handler<Message<String>>) event ->
    {
      handleDestruction(event.body());
    });
  }
```

Debugging I have seen that this class is created only when somewhere in the code there is written

```
@Inject
DefaultCounterTracker counterTracker
```

I have tried binding using a provider but nothing changes: it seems that if the class is not referenced Guice won't create it. Is there a way to tell Guice to do it? Did I miss the point?

I could also create the instance manually but if I do change in default implementation of one of the parameters (EventBus for instance) I need to remember also to change the call in the constructor.

Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the mentioned class is supposed to be a Singleton, then you can create an object of this class eagerly by specifying a binding in your configure() method of the AbstractModule class.

```
bind(DefaultCounterTracker.class).to(DefaultCounterTracker.class).asEagerSingleton();
```